# What is a good starting point for understanding how graphics work on a Virtual Machine?

Tags: drivers, graphics, virtualbox, vmware

Some of my graphics show up as expected and others do not.  What is a good starting point for understanding how graphics work on a Virtual Machine?

My adapter name is VMware SVGA 3D
Driver Version 8.15.1.33
Generic Non-PnP Monitor.

Comment: This is a very broad question and VMWare is closed source so I am not sure there are any technical specifications.

Answer (score 1):

> In virtual and remote desktop environments, it is particularly difficult to render and deliver complex graphics to endpoints with adequate performance. The standard GPU was originally developed to offload processing calculations from the CPU for graphics-intensive applications.  NVIDIA introduced the first virtual GPU in 2012 to help solve that problem, reducing lag time when delivering graphics to remote users and providing the same performance they would get from a PC. This is especially useful for users that require computer-aided design or 3-D graphics applications.

-[TechTarget](http://searchvirtualdesktop.techtarget.com/definition/virtual-GPU-vGPU)

This explains that there are such things as **Virtual** GPUs. Like the OP stated, they wanted a starting point. Virtual GPU's are the things that you want to search for when learning about Virtual Machine graphics. These are the things that handle the rendering in VMs and I think that's what you want to learn about.